# jQuery increase box to show overflow contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm loading some lines of text in each of some div boxes (category listing). I need it shows only three on load. So I limited the height and set overflow:hidden; css to make it happen. I have a small button (image loaded in div) next to the box for increasing and decreasing the box height. The problem is this item doesn't work properly. Here are the codes (I'll leave the other unrelated HTML/CSS/jQuery codes):

HTML (one of the boxes in the page):

```
<div class="content" style="height:50px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div>Category 1</div>
    <div>Category 2</div>
    <div>Category 3</div>
    <div>Category 4</div>
    <div>Category 5</div>
    <div>Category 6</div>
</div>
<div class="see-more"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".see-more").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).prev("div.content").height(200);
    });
});
```

The jQuery code seems having problems. I also need to know how can I find the real height of hidden content (because of overflow) to set the exact height to the box instead of static 200 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the inner items and use the height of that container to determine max height of items. You could do some calcs to increment the height in steps... following sets the full height

```
$(function(){
    $('.content').wrapInner('<div class="inner">');  

    $(".see-more").click(function() {
        var $cont=$(this).prev()
        var maxHeight = $cont.find('.inner').height();
        $cont.height(maxHeight);
    });
 });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nq2Em/1/

Comment: The idea seems to be work and demo was okay. But I clouldn't use in my code and I need a little more time to fix it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: not sure if you are using noConflict() and need to convert `$` to `jQuery`...I just always write `$`...much faster

Comment: oops! I've told you there is many of these boxes in the page :D can you show me how to select only the related one?! I mean the content tag came before the see-more.

Comment: OK..I adjusted for multiple boxes. Updated demo for several boxes also

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scrollHeight property to get the real height if the container, or in case you don't want to do any kind of animation, you could also simply remove the overflow hidden. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/qssuA/) shows the height solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".see-more").click(function() {
        var box = jQuery(this).prev("div.content"),
            height = box[0].scrollHeight;
        box.height(height);
    });
});​
```